# Open AND 'activate' tab within Jetbrains IDEs using ENTER?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

Annoyingly, in ALL Jetbrains IDEs, when you press ENTER to open a file in a new tab, the tab does not also become active.

For example when navigating within the project window using arrow keys, when i then open a file using ENTER, i have to additionally invoke the 'switcher' with ctrl + tab if i want to start moving about/typing within that file.

This is very very annoying as it is pretty standard in IDEs that when you open a file, it also becomes active.

If i double-click the file the opened tab does become active - but i don't want to use the mouse or trackpad, it's annoying and tiring. It seems a shame to have so many keyboard shortcuts only to make the user return to the mouse/trackpad just for that ...

IS THERE a shortcut key to do this? Any setting i can change? I have looked hard but haven't even found other people complaining about this - they must be there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer: assign the keyboard shortcut ENTER to the command "Jump to source".

This can be declared in XML keymap file like this:

```
<action id="EditSource">
  <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ENTER" />
</action>
```